# Is it possible to set more than one name and value to one PropertyInfo in android?

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

Im creating android application that can connect to a web service using soap client(WSDL). Now I want to know if it's possible to create a request using PropertyInfo and set more than one name and value to it. I have this code for more info about my question.

```
        String METHOD_NAME = "callLog";
        String NAMESPACE = "http://sasd.logpos.com/appservs/app/customize/qwe/ecq.wsdl/";
        String URL = "http://sasd.logpos.com/appservs/app/customize/qwe/ecqsoap.php";
        String SOAP_ACTION = "http://sasd.logpos.com/appservs/app/customize/qwe/ecq.wsdl/callLog";
        Log.i("myEmpId", myEmpId);
        Log.i("myPassword", myPassword);
        //create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        //create param
        PropertyInfo paramsEmpId = new PropertyInfo();
        paramsEmpId.setName("authuserid");
        paramsEmpId.setValue(myEmpId);
        paramsEmpId.setType(String.class);


        paramsPass.setName("authpassword");
        paramsPass.setValue(myPassword);
        paramsPass.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(paramsEmpId, "LOGON");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String response = null;
        try {
            response = envelope.getResponse().toString();
        } catch (SoapFault e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add as many `PropertyInfo`

I found one more problem with the `URL` that you are using it should always be a `WSDL` url and Check your `Namespace` as well.

```
//create param
        PropertyInfo paramsEmpId = new PropertyInfo();
        paramsEmpId.setName("authuserid");
        paramsEmpId.setValue(myEmpId);
        paramsEmpId.setType(String.class);

        PropertyInfo paramsPass= new PropertyInfo();// Create a new propertyInfo
        paramsPass.setName("authpassword");
        paramsPass.setValue(myPassword);
        paramsPass.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(paramsEmpId);// Changed here
        request.addProperty(paramsPass); // Changed here
```

Comment: how should I know what is my url and what is my namespace?

Comment: @NewDroidDev this is not the wsdl url? for example it should be like http://www.webservicex.net/WeatherForecast.asmx

Comment: @NewDroidDev for both the url am getting 404 server error. So first get the correct url.

Answer (score 0):

```
       yes this possible and  hope this is going to help you

      please check the lines


 paramsPassInfo paramsPass= new paramsPassInfo();

        paramsPass.setName("authpassword");
        paramsPass.setValue(myPassword);
        paramsPass.setType(String.class);

  request.addProperty(paramsPass, "//name");
```